# Keras transfer learning by freezing conv_base gives poor accuracy compared with training "pre cached" features

Tags: keras, transfer-learning

I am doing transfer learning with Keras 2.1.6 with 2 very well known standard ways. Both of which are detailed at length in Chapter 5 of Chollet's book and in https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.3-using-a-pretrained-convnet.ipynb

The 2 ways are summarily:

A) Caching the representation from conv_base and then train on your FC separately.
This is deemed fast but doesnt allow data augmentation in Keras.

B) Extend the conv_base model with your FC and freeze the conv_base weights, and train end to end. This is expensive to train on CPU but will allow more flexibility, in particular, adding data augmentation.

For my particular dataset and using MobileNet (instead of VGG), i tried both ways. Method (A) will give me about 75% validation accuracy after 10 epochs but Method (B) will only give me ~58% (without data augmentation). However, I expect them to be roughly the same. I tried to debug and see what I did majorly wrong but couldn't spot any.

One thing I read is the weights that were supposedly frozen in method B) may not be frozen due to bugs in the past. But current Keras version 2.1.6 should be free of this. Here is how I froze the weights in conv_base.

```
conv_base.trainable = False
for layer in conv_base.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

The loop may not be needed but I added it just in case. I verified that weights were in fact frozen by checking on them after a few epochs. So this is probably not whats causing the problem.

Anyone who has a hint on how to debug, or what can go wrong, please let me know.

I posted both runs as a GitHub gists. I ran this on google colab and exported them. The relevant portion should start with those Keras imports.

Method A): https://gist.github.com/kechan/38b4e6c85501246a2a49deadd26aefd7

Method B): https://gist.github.com/kechan/f3fea62279ac847e9adc100351b7e9e8

### Update

I have further combined the 2 ways of transfer learning into one notebook and tried to keep everything else "constant" as much as possible. here's the new gist:

https://gist.github.com/kechan/9487fad4dfeaede212e3d9899fb21105

Comment: I have actually combined the 2 into one notebook to highlight what I am seeing: https://gist.github.com/kechan/9487fad4dfeaede212e3d9899fb21105

Comment: Update: I tested VGG16, MobileNet, and Xception as my conv_base (include_top=False). I think VGG16 has the smallest discrepancies while MobileNet and Xception has larger differences. So the architecture may matter. One thing that VGG16 doesnt have is batch norm. I begin to suspect there may be a "issue" on how you freeze, train, etc involving batch norm layer.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm tackling a similar issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692071/data-augmentation-hurts-accuracy-keras

Comment: In fact, I have doubt about the statement in the book. I could not reproduce the result using exactly the same code(+ freezing) for VGG16. Actually, when I turned off the freezing, the training result was much closer to the curves(val acc went to 96%-97%) in the book.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an effect of the `BatchNormalization` layers (BN), or any other layers, that work differently in training vs. inference. BN in particular uses saved population stats in inference but current mini-batch stats in training. What happens when you freeze the weights of a BN layer in your base model and then train, is that the mini-batch stats will be used. This can lead to bad results as the neighboring conv layers expect inputs normalized using the saved population stats.

You do not see any bad effects if you first extract the features using the base model because the base model is in inference mode and the population stats are used.

A solution is to subclass `BatchNormalization` and override the `__call__` method setting the `training` flag to False. Something like the following:

```py
class InferenceBatchNormalization(BatchNormalization):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BatchNormalization, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        return super(BatchNormalization, self).__call__(inputs, training=False)
```

Have a look at the keras code and it will become clear: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/normalization.py#L132