# Data Augmentation hurts accuracy Keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning, data-augmentation

I'm trying to adapt **Deep Learning with Python** *section 5.3 Feature extraction with Data Augmentation* to a 3-class problem with resnet50 (imagenet weights).

Full code at https://github.com/morenoh149/plantdisease

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras import optimizers
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

input_shape = (224, 224, 3)
target_size = (224, 224)
batch_size = 20

conv_base = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', input_shape=input_shape, include_top=False)

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

conv_base.trainable = False

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'input/train',
    target_size=target_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'input/validation',
    target_size=target_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),
             metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=96,
    epochs=30,
    verbose=2,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=48)
```

Questions:

- the book doesn't go much into ImageDataGenerator and selecting `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps`. What should these values be?
  I have 3 classes, 1000 images each. I've split it 60/20/20 train/validation/test.
- I was able to get a validation accuracy of 60% without data augmentation. Above I've simplified the ImageDataGenerator to only rescale. This model has a validation accuracy of 30% Why?
- What changes do I need to make to the data-augmented version of this script to match the accuracy with no augmentation?

UPDATE:
This may be an issue with keras itself

- https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9214
- https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9965

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: `steps_per_epoch`is the number of batches the training generator should yield before considering an epoch finished. If you have 600 training images with batch size 20, this would be 30 steps per epoch et cetera. `validation_steps` applies the same logic to the validation data generator, be it at the end of each epoch.

In general, `steps_per_epoch` is the size of your dataset divided by the batch size.

Comment: What happens to the model if you set steps_per_epoch higher than samples/batch_size? Why is validation_steps demonstrated as samples/batch_size/2 not validation_samples/batch_size?

Comment: You will get an error saying that the generator ran out of data. Not sure why it is demonstrated that way in the example.

Comment: I just tried increase steps_per_epoch and there is no error. I think it performs random augmentations of the batched samples. Which ties into my questions. If you set spe to (2*samples)/batch_size are you "doubling" your dataset? The choice for validations_steps coincidentally was samples/batch_size/2 because the validation set was half the size of the training set in the book.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the `ImageDataGenerator` seems to yield indefinitely. So yes, if you set spe to 2*samples/batch_size you will double your dataset (without any form of random augmentation you would just end up with two duplicates of your data ofcourse).